# Backup using FTP

Tags: backup, local

I got a question about backing up my website. How do I make sure I have downloaded all, copying the files locally using FTP? I left the terminal to work and a copy of Magento folder was created on my PC, but I ask because at the first attempt I was disconnect.

Comment: Don't use ftp to backup your magento instance. It has about 16-17k files. It will take forever.

Comment: So what do you suggest? I cannot complete the backup through the admin control panel because it logs me out ^^' I thought FTP was the solution. I already downloaded the files, I just don't know if they are all there. I don't think so, because the local folder weights only 66MB

Comment: versioning system, even a simple archive is better than downloading 17k files. There is also the option to backup the server from the admin panel System->Tools->Backup but I've seen it back-fire a few times.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie, first time I'm using Magento. Versioning system what does it mean? Something like that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655733/which-magento-website-directories-and-files-not-to-backup-with-cloud-backup-solu
Because the backup option from the admin panel it doesn't work, I don't know why

Comment: he meant something like [SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (here Tortoise if you're on Windows), or [Git](https://github.com/) which are versionning system, they'll allow you to go back to a previous stable state of development in case you need to.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer this in a more general way with regards to source control.

When I am working with Magento projects I use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) as a source control system and do nightly database backups from my servers. This allows me to keep a track of all data changes by admin users and also helps me to track what code changes have been made in the project.

Then I make sure that I deploy any changes via a git checkout of a [tag](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging), so that I know what exactly is and isn't live and make sure all changes are committed and deployed in this way rather than via ftp.

Having everything under source control, including Magento core, allows me to checkout the system locally easily and I can easily download the latest database backup and use this as the database for my local system. It will also make sure changes are not lost or overridden and provides an overview of what has changed, by who and when.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from GIT (which is highly recommended) there are other ways to create a traditional "backup" of Magento. There are [multiple ways to backup Magento](http://www.snapfast.com/blog/magento-backup-methods/) that would be MUCH better than trying to download via FTP including SSH, control panel, and the standard built-in Magento backup method.

If you're just trying to copy down all the files via FTP it takes forever / kills your session because it has to make a request for each individual file (roughly 15k files or more) and this is insane. Instead make a backup on the server and put everything into 1 or 2 compressed files (.tar.gz or .zip) and then use FTP to download that 1 file.

It's like trying to ship 15,000 pieces of junk to your friend. Would you rather stick them all in a box and ship it in 1 piece or ship each item individually? It's the same thing.